# Random characters showing up on second computer

Tags: networking

When I compose an email and type letters on one computer it also shows up in a completely different program on another computer...Ie...I am typing a not and all of a sudden I get random characters showing up coming from another computer using email.  How can I stop this?

Comment: Are you using remote desktops? Have you done a malware sweep?

Comment: Are you using wireless keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

Background - each character in a set has a unique binary address to what that symbol is. Fonts use that address to determine what letter or symbol to draw. Trouble is, different languages have more/less characters, and they're not always placed in the SAME place in the character set - so where one (my) set sees ascii code 21 as "§", a different language might use code 21 for another strange character - not intended to be used by the author - its just what their keyboard picked. When the server got that character as its character address (encoded in ascii, or unicode, etc) the server thought the character referred to the server's definition of that character.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_set

Comment: Please explain **how** that answers the question.

Comment: We are using remote desktop, it is turned on all the computer but only one computer is being affected by the front office computer and it is the furthest one away.  Not sure why the when someone types on the front computer it can also show up on the computer in the back and in a different program, any help?